# dlsym() usage fails for rand

Tags: c++, macos, dynamic-library

I'm trying to call `rand` using `dlfcn.h` (d.

I have [this code](https://gist.github.com/jjpe/df251ba65a8c34f9412e), based on a project I'm working on. The core issue for me is that when used this way, it compiles and even runs, but its output is

```
cif: cif is OK
rand val: 16807
```

And the value of `rand val` is 16807 every time, contrary to what `rand` is supposed to do. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have you set a seed with srand()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only call `rand()` once. If unseeded, `rand()` is probably going to use a static seed, probably zero (library-dependent).

Import `srand` too, and seed it with a reasonably random quantity - for example, you could do

```
timeval tv;
gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
srand_ptr(tv.tv_sec ^ tv.tv_usec);
```

to seed it with the current time (seconds and microseconds).

Alternatively, on OS X, consider using [`arc4random`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html) instead, which is automatically seeded and generally produces better random numbers.